# Debugging a IndexOutOfRangeException in WinDBG

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg, indexoutofboundsexception

i am trying to debug some .NET executable (that i don't have the source code for) which is acting strange.

When attaching to it using WinDBG, i've noticed it's throwing an IndexOutOfRangeException.

I am trying to understand which line is actually throwing this exception -- how can i see the index access that is causing this?

I can see the stack using !CLRStack but it doesn't lead me to the exact line of code that threw it.

This is what i see in !CLRStack :

```
 0015ec9c 6f1459d8 System.Management.Instrumentation.InstrumentedAssembly+TypeInfo.Fire(System.Object)
0015eccc 6f144bdc System.Management.Instrumentation.InstrumentedAssembly.Fire(System.Type, System.Object)
0015ecd8 6f145164 System.Management.Instrumentation.InstrumentedAssembly.Fire(System.Object)
0015ecec 6f142268 System.Management.Instrumentation.Instrumentation.Fire(System.Object)
0015ecf8 034ce47b InstallerLibrary.InstallerInterface.WMIEventGenerator.FireEvent(System.Object)
0015ed2c 0393970c InstallerLibrary.InstallerInterface.WMIEventGenerator.GenerateServerAlive(UInt32)
0015ed54 039396b7 InstallerLibrary.InstallerInterface.InstallerInterface.NotifyServerAlive(UInt32)
0015ed60 03939655 InstallerLibrary.InstallaterManager.NotifyServerAlive(UInt32)
0015ed88 00580f13 InstallerInit.Class1.Main(System.String[])
```

Comment: What are you going to do with it if you don't have the code?

Comment: I will contact the team that is responsible for it to tell them where exactly it is failing, as they are not testing it on real systems.

Comment: just send them the stack trace. they'll tell you what further info is required.

Comment: Raising this issue to them without anything solid will be discarded as "cannot reproduce on our system". I'd like to show exactly what part of code is failing. Is this possible ?

Comment: Send them process dump. Create one with `.dump /ma` command. The fact that they cannot reproduce problem in house is not an excuse, it is a manifestation of either ignorance or incompetence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line number information is stored in pdbs. If you don't have privat symbols the !clrstack won't be able to provide that

The sosex extension can provide IL offset when using !mk even when there isn't pdbs.

To see the index access that is causing this you would have look at the locals using !clrstack -a or using sosex !mdv

Comment: If i'd get the symbols, what are the commands needed to spot the failing line? or it would appear automatically when running !PrintException ? Since the stack trace is listing that the top of the stack is a System.Management.Instrumentation method and not code written by our company.

Answer (score 0):

Use !dso to dump the stack objects at the time of exception. You will be getting the index also as an integer in the stack. This will help you in narrowing down on the code.

Also use !dumpheap -type IndexOutOfRangeException. And note the object address(say xxx). Now use !pe xxx to see the exception stack for IndexOutOfRangeException.